# UnityKinectDepthExplorer - how can I use this example with Kinect v1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm interested in displaying Depth data in Unity with Kinect for Windows. Unfortunately, I have Kinect v1.8 and I know this has been easily done with Kinect V2 (Kinect Fusion).

I found this example: https://github.com/rickbarraza/UnityKinectDepthExplorer
I installed all the necessary components and now getting DLLNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION:

Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/x86_64/KinectUnityAddin.dll'

Concerning all the posts and forums I've been reading so far, It's because I'm using SDK 1.8 (instead of SDK 2.0).

Is there any way how I can use this example with Kinect v1.8? I tried to contact the author as well but he haven't responded back.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem in an University Project maby its not to late for you.
This is an Kinect v1.8 Wrapper i made to read the kinect depth image only. I used the Kinect with MS-SDK from the Unity-Assetstore as an orientation, you dont have to download it. All you need is this Code.
Use The Init() Method to start and the GetDepthArray() Function to get the Deapth Frame.
hope it works for you !

You have to install the Kinect 1.8 sdk or have at least the Kinect10.dll from the 1.8 sdk in your Windows/System32 folder

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class OwnKinectWrapper : MonoBehaviour {

DepthBuffer db;

#region Nui Variables/Structs/Intefraces
IntPtr streamReferenz;

public struct NuiImageViewArea
{
    public int eDigitalZoom;
    public int lCenterX;
    public int lCenterY;
}

public struct NuiSurfaceDesc
{
    uint width;
    uint height;
}

public struct DepthBuffer
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 640 * 480, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort[] pixels;
}

public struct NuiLockedRect
{
    public int pitch;
    public int size;
    public IntPtr pBits;

}
public struct NuiImageFrame
{
    public Int64 liTimeStamp;
    public uint dwFrameNumber;
    public int eImageType;
    public int eResolution;
    public IntPtr pFrameTexture;
    public uint dwFrameFlags_NotUsed;
    public NuiImageViewArea ViewArea_NotUsed;
}



[Guid("13ea17f5-ff2e-4670-9ee5-1297a6e880d1")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComImport()]
public interface INuiFrameTexture
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int BufferLen();
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int Pitch();
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int LockRect(uint Level, ref NuiLockedRect pLockedRect, IntPtr pRect, uint Flags);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetLevelDesc(uint Level, ref NuiSurfaceDesc pDesc);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int UnlockRect(uint Level);
}
#endregion
// Use this for initialization
public int Init() {
    int init = 0;
    try {
        init = NuiInitialize(0x00000020);
        Debug.Log("init : " + init);

        streamReferenz = IntPtr.Zero;
        NuiImageStreamOpen(4, 2, 0, 2, IntPtr.Zero, ref streamReferenz);



    }
    catch (DllNotFoundException e)
    {
        string message = "Please check the Kinect SDK installation.";
        Debug.LogError(message);
        Debug.LogError(e.ToString());

        return -1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError(e.ToString());

        return -1;
    }

    return init;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    IntPtr imageStreamFrameReferenz = IntPtr.Zero;
    int test = NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(streamReferenz, 0, ref imageStreamFrameReferenz);
    if (test == 0) {
        NuiImageFrame imageFrame = (NuiImageFrame)Marshal.PtrToStructure(imageStreamFrameReferenz, typeof(NuiImageFrame));
        INuiFrameTexture frameTexture = (INuiFrameTexture)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(imageFrame.pFrameTexture);

        NuiLockedRect lockedRectPtr = new NuiLockedRect();
        IntPtr r = IntPtr.Zero;
        frameTexture.LockRect(0, ref lockedRectPtr, r, 0);
        db = (DepthBuffer)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lockedRectPtr.pBits, typeof(DepthBuffer));
        frameTexture.UnlockRect(0);
        NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(streamReferenz, imageStreamFrameReferenz);
    }
}

void OnDisable() {
    NuiShutdown();
}

public ushort[] GetDepthArray(){
    return db.pixels;
}


[DllImportAttribute(@"Kinect10.dll",EntryPoint="NuiInitialize")]
public static extern int NuiInitialize (uint dwFlags);


[DllImportAttribute(@"Kinect10.dll", EntryPoint = "NuiImageStreamOpen")]
public static extern int NuiImageStreamOpen(int enumImageType,int enumImgageResolution, uint image_Flags, uint frameBufferLimit, IntPtr nextFrameEvent, ref IntPtr streamHandle );


[DllImportAttribute(@"Kinect10.dll", EntryPoint = "NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame")]
public static extern int NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(IntPtr streamReferenz, uint dwMillisecondsToWait, ref IntPtr ImageFrameReferenz);


[DllImportAttribute(@"Kinect10.dll", EntryPoint = "NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame")]
public static extern int NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(IntPtr phStreamHandle, IntPtr ppcImageFrame);


[DllImportAttribute(@"Kinect10.dll",EntryPoint="NuiDepthPixelToDepth")]
public static extern ushort NuiDepthPixelToDepth (ushort depthPixel);


[DllImportAttribute(@"Kinect10.dll", EntryPoint = "NuiShutdown")]
public static extern void NuiShutdown();


}
```

if something is not working or you need help feel free to write some lines